# Sign convention-moment

Tags: moments

[image]

I am having a hard time taking care of signs. Whether we’ve made the cut at right or at left. Whether should we make the rotation according to axis x, y or z.
In this case, they assumed that P was applied at the left of the axis of rotation and obtained M as negative. Why couldn’t we assumed that P is at right as well and with the calculations shown be positive?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bending_moment#Sign_conventions for more clarity on why sign conventions are what they are.

Answer (score 1):

Both moments tend to turn the plate in the same direction (counter-clockwise). So both should have the same sign. If you use convention used in the book, then both are negative: https://classes.mst.edu/civeng2210/concepts/07/internal/index.html

However, if you use the screw rule both are positive: http://www2.eng.cam.ac.uk/~hemh1/gyroscopes/screwrule.html

So both must have the same sign and the result is then the same.

Comment: in the figure at left,M is shown to be counterclockwise to positive according to our conventions. However, in the formula at right they used M as negative

Comment: And assuming the force was at the right of the axis it should’ve been positive and opposite to the counterclockwise direction of the one shown at the cut

Comment: True. Then the moment and the moment created by the force should have opposite signs.